# Ionic2 - tabsHideOnSubPages misbehaving

Tags: angular, tabs, ionic2, hide

I have a tabbed app with a multi-page form, accessed from within one of the tabs. The first time the user goes through this form, the tabs are gone from the bottom of the screen, as expected. After the user navigates to the last page in the form I use a setRoot(TabsPage) to bring the user back to the initial tabbed page. If the user re-enters the form, however, the tabs appear at the bottom of the screen.

Why does this happen? Is it a bug with Ionic2 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was setting the root on the stack back to my tabbed page, when I needed to be setting the root to the specific page that I wanted to go to.

So, to illustrate:

TabbedPage contained tabs a, b, c, and d. TabbedPage defaulted to page d.

setRoot(TabbedPage) got me to the page I wanted (d), but then caused the unintended behavior when navigating after that.

setRoot(d) got me to the page I wanted without the undesired behavior.